# How to find the odd numbers in a given range in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Shown below is the code to print the odd numbers in a given range of integers.

When I'm using the `return` keyword, it's checking the `3` and returning the `num`, so the output is `3`, but this is not the required output I'm looking for. The required output is `3,5`.

In another case when I'm using the `print` function instead of `return`, the program checks 3,4,5 and returns '3 & 5' as the output.

Could help me to get the right output

```py
def oddNumbers(l, r):

    # iterating each number in list
    for num in range(l, r + 1):

        # checking condition
        if num % 2 != 0:

            return num
```

Comment: Your code currently returns after it finds the first odd. You need to store the current odd numbers every iteration and return outside of your loop. Also, why not just find the first odd and step by 2 until you reach the upper bound instead of iterating through all the numbers between?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to go through the range. Take a look at the first number: if it is odd, build a new range with the step of 2 that starts at that number. If it is even, then start at the next number.

```
def oddNumbers(l, r):
    if l % 2 == 1: 
        return list(range(l,     r + 1, 2))
    else: 
        return list(range(l + 1, r + 1, 2))
```

Or, in a more Pythonic way:

```
def oddNumbers(l, r):
    return list(range(l if l % 2 else l + 1, r + 1, 2))
```

Comment: Or even `range(l | 1, r + 1, 2)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following approach which stores the interim values in a list named `odd` and returns the list after going through the range of numbers between `l` and `r`:

```
def oddNumbers(l, r):
    odd = []
    # iterating each number in list
    for num in range(l, r + 1):

        # checking condition
        if num % 2 != 0:
            odd.append(num)
    return odd
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using list comprehension:

```
def odd(l,u):
    return([a for a in range(l,u) if a%2 != 0])
```